# When to use asInstanceOf?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I'm trying out scalajs and am quite confused about how to access DOM elements using the org.scalajs.dom.html package.
By trial and error, I've discovered that some elements need to be cast to certain types using `asInstanceOf`, but some do not. Is there a general rule as to when and where `asInstanceOf` needs to be used?

For example, say I have a `input` element with id `myinput`. In order to access the value of the input I need to use `asInstanceOf`:

```
val content = document.getElementById("myinput").asInstanceOf[html.Input].value
```

But when it comes time to display `content` in my `div` of id `contentdiv`, the compiler didn't complain when I did not use `asInstanceOf` on the `div` element:

```
val mydiv = document.getElementById("contentdiv")
mydiv.innerHTML = content
```

Also, as a bonus is there a central place to find all the possible `asInstanceOf` arguments and a mapping of them to actual HTML elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of `getElementById` is

```
def getElementById(id: String): DOMElement
```

and `DOMElement` is defined as

```
trait DOMElement extends js.Object {
  var innerHTML: String = js.native

  def appendChild(child: DOMElement): Unit = js.native
}
```

So, whenever you call `getElementById` you get a `DOMElement` back and the only operations you can perform on it are `innerHTML` and `appendChild`.

That's why your last example works without explicit casting.

But `DOMElement` is a very generic type. Sometimes you **know** that `getElementById` will return - say - an `<input>` element.

And that's when you can use `asInstanceOf` to inform the compiler about this extra piece of knowledge you have.

```
document.getElementById("myinput").asInstanceOf[html.Input].value
                                      ^
                                      |
          hey compiler, I KNOW this is going to be an html.Input,
            please let me do my things and explode otherwise.
```

Needless to say, you need to be careful when using `asInstanceOf`. If you are wrong, the compiler won't be able to save you from a runtime crash this time.

Comment: interesting. what's special about innerHTML and appendChild that they are included where others are not? are these two the largest possible set of common methods in the prototype chain of the universe of DOM elements?

Comment: No, there are a bunch of other things: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalajs/dom/raw/Html.scala#L3736 The answer here just mentioned a few things to keep the answer short.

Comment: @sjrd thanks for chiming in. Quick question, I couldn't find an actual `DOMElement` definition in the library (the one I posted is from the reversi example). What am I missing?

Comment: oh nevermind, I got. They're all native js so they're mapped with `js.native`, including `getElementById`

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of your question:

> is there a central place to find all the possible `asInstanceOf` arguments and a mapping of them to actual HTML elements?

You can search for "extends HTMLElement" in [Html.scala](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalajs/dom/raw/Html.scala).